# Preg_replace do not exist in php7. What can i do?

Tags: php

I have a form where i get a filename from a inputbox. I create the a directory and change the extension form "gpx" to "xml" of the file before i upload the file to my directory.
In php5 i need preg_replace, but in php i can't do it anymore.

I have this code:
  My old code is:

```
  if (!file_exists($dirPath)) {
    mkdir($dirPath, 0755,true);
    }
    $target = '/'.$mappe.'/'; 
    $target = $dirPath .'/'. basename( $_FILES['gpsfilnavn']['name']); 
        $target =    preg_replace("/(\w+).gpx/ie","$1.'.xml'",$target);    
        $xmlfil = $xmlfil . basename( $_FILES['gpsfilnavn']['name']); 
        $xmlfil =    preg_replace("/(\w+).gpx/ie","$1.'.xml'",$xmlfil);     
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['gpsfilnavn']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['gpsfilnavn']['name'])." has been  uploaded";
```

Can anybody help me what i have to change?

Comment: Um... preg_replace does exist in PHP7...

Comment: `preg_replace` is very much available in PHP7. [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: FROM THE MANUAL: **7.0.0 Support for the /e modifier has been removed. Use preg_replace_callback() instead.** A strange place to look I know, but it is always worth a try

Comment: sure, `preg_replace` itself exists, but `/e` modifier does not.

Answer (score 2):

There has been a change since PHP 7 regarding the `preg_replace()` function.
According to the [man-page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

> 7.0.0     Support for the /e modifier has been removed. Use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) instead.

Maybe this helps you?

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon this issue today when upgrading a phpBB-based website from PHP5 to PHP7. I came up with three different workarounds that can be used for different scenarios, the second one being the only viable one for mine since I had template-based regexp stored within the filesystem/db instead of static ones, which I couldn't easily alter.

Basically, I went from this:

```
$input = preg_replace($search, $replace, $input);
```

to something like this:

```
$input = preg_replace($search, 
    function($m) use ($replace) { 
        $rep = $replace; 
        for ($i = 1; $i<count($m); $i++) { 
            $rep = str_replace('\\'.$i, '$m['.$i.']', $rep); 
            $rep = str_replace('\$'.$i, '$m['.$i.']', $rep); 
        }
        eval('$str='.$rep); 
        return $str;
    },
    $input);
```

Needless to say, this is nothing more than a *quick-and-dirty* workaround, only "viable" for those who cannot easily refactor their code with the updated **preg_replace_callback** function without having to use any potentially unsecure `eval()` call: for this very reason it should only be used if the developer has full control over the replacement strings/rules and is able to properly test/debug them. That said, in my specific scenario, I was able to effectively use that in order to get the job done.

**IMPORTANT:** the `str_replace` and/or the `eval()` could break some replacement rules unless they are "properly" defined taking the above code into account.

For further info regarding this issue and other alternative workarounds you can also read [this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/php-fix-warning-preg_replace-e-modifier-no-longer-supported-error-php7/) on my blog.